# npm: "--save"-flag necessary to write dependencies to "package.json"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

Is the "--save"-flag really necessary to write an installed dependency to the "package.json"-file.

I have tried it out without the "save"-flag and the package was afterward nevertheless within the "dependencies"-section. So the adding seem to be default-behaviour.

So, therefore my question: **What benefit provides the standard "save"?** **Or can one leave it as well**?

Not the "save-dev". That's clear to me.

Comment: no benefit. it used to be required to update package.json. now it's not

Comment: @EricGuan Yep. Matches with what I have seen ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of [npm 5.0.0](http://blog.npmjs.org/post/161081169345/v500), installed modules are added as a dependency by default, so the `--save` option is no longer needed. The other save options still exist and are listed in the [documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install) for `npm install`.